# How run glue job locally?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I have setup project as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html#develop-local-scala). But code:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.{AWSGlueClientBuilder, GlueContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

object MyGlueJob {
  private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
  def main(sysArgs: Array[String]) {

    val spark: SparkContext = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(spark)
    val awsGlueClient = AWSGlueClientBuilder.defaultClient
  }
}
```

fails with error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
19/11/21 15:40:32 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.3
19/11/21 15:40:33 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2544)
    at MyGlueJob$.main(MyGlueJob.scala:13)
    at MyGlueJob.main(MyGlueJob.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:66)
19/11/21 15:40:33 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$postApplicationEnd(SparkContext.scala:2416)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1930)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2544)
    at MyGlueJob$.main(MyGlueJob.scala:13)
    at MyGlueJob.main(MyGlueJob.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:66)
19/11/21 15:40:33 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:66)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2544)
    at MyGlueJob$.main(MyGlueJob.scala:13)
    at MyGlueJob.main(MyGlueJob.scala)
    ... 5 more
```

It is obvious that master url should be set but how to this from commandline or system variables? (E.g. without touching the code)

Also I have [read] that `--master` argument can fix problem, but adding it to args do nothing (here is Intellij Idea run configuration):

[image]

The key question is to run glue job locally and be able to run it in aws without code touching, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can created a spark session explicitly and set any parameters you want. But I cannot say that this will work eventually in Glue. The following is a local session that I use to test Spark jobs locally even though I do run them eventually in Glue. I test only pure spark code.

```
  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("hduser"))
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("spark unit test")
      .getOrCreate()
  }
```

> The key question is to run glue job locally and be able to run it in aws without code touching, is it possible?

It's possible to run any code with a dev endpoint and Zeppelin. See [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-notebook.html).